# Master page and asp.net content page event firing sequence

Tags: asp.net

When master page event fires, content page events are fired first,

Can anybody help me know, is there any content page event that fires after the master page events.

Answer (score 1):

Which event are you using already in the master page? There are most likely enough page events to consider which fire afterwards.

Take a look at the [ASP.NET Page life cycle](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/ASPNET20PageLifeCycle.aspx) for it.

Edit after comment:

You can grab the Session data again in the content page in the **PreRender** event. However depending on your needs that may be too late in the life cycle already.

Besides this all, session state should be used between pages, not to pass data from a master page to a content page. Instead make use of the [**HttpContext.Items**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) instead.

Yet another way is to raise a custom event from the master page and handle it in the content page.

Comment: actually i have an imagebutton_onclick event in master page and on its basis i want to set some session variables that are to be used in content page.

As the content page events are fired before the master page events, thats why those session variable being accessed in content page have the old values and after the page is loaded master page contents are  changed whereas the content page contents are not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is [Events in ASP.NET Master and Content Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
There are importatntly four events where content page events are fired after master page's related event:

1. Content controls Init event
2. Content page Init event.
3. Content page controls Load event.
4. Content page controls PreRender event.

Answer (score 0):

```
Event sequence:-

Content page PreInit event.

Master page controls Init event.

Content controls Init event.

Master page Init event.

Content page Init event.

Content page Load event.

Master page Load event.

Master page controls Load event.

Content page controls Load event.

Content page PreRender event.

Master page PreRender event.

Master page controls PreRender event.

Content page controls PreRender event.

Master page controls Unload event.

Content page controls Unload event.

Master page Unload event.

Content page Unload event.
```